# How to get Current Entry ID in Plugin Variable?

Tags: plugin-development, variable

I need to get the current entry ID in plugin's variable file without submitting any form. I tried this but it gave an error **Undefined property: Craft\PluginNameVariable::$element**

```
namespace Craft;

class PluginNameVariable
{
/**
 */
public function totalitemsForElements($elements = array())
{
    $criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria('MyElementType');

    $criteria->elementId = $this->element->id;

    $items = $criteria->find();

    return $criteria->find();
}
}
```

I was accessing this variable through

```
{% set itemElementType =  craft.pluginName.totalitemsForElements %}
{{ itemElementType|length }}
```

Please Help. Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like what you want is to get elements related to an entry that is pre-loaded in a template, and that `elementId` is a custom field for `MyElementType`. If that's the case, this should work out:

```
public function totalitemsForElements($elementID)
{
    $criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria('MyElementType');

    $criteria->elementId = $elementID;

    return $criteria->find();
}
```

We'll pass the entry id to the variable function. Here's the template code:

```
{% set itemElementType =  craft.pluginName.totalitemsForElements(entry.id) %}
{{ itemElementType|length }}
```